# Bootstrap 5 underlined text showing in iPhone

Tags: html, css, underline

I am using Bootstrap version 5.1.3. I completed a project and when I check the mobile version via a real device(iPhone XS) all anchor tags (`<a href="#">Something</a>`) have underlined text. When I start the CSS I am using the below codes to remove underlined text.

```
a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:focus-visible, a:active {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Whether I use this to remove underlined text it is there for iPhones. Not for Android mobiles.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add One more `a:focus`

Comment: @LaljiTadhani added and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-decoration: none !important;
```

Use important hope this works well!

Thanks.

Comment: Even this code is not working

Answer (score 0):

```css
a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:focus-visible, a:focus, a:active {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none !important; 
}
```

hope this works well!

Comment: Even this code is not working

Answer (score 0):

**I am posting this if anyone facing the same.**

There is a built-in class for `text-decoration:none` in Bootstrap `5.1.3`. Using that solved the problem for me.

```
<a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">Anything</a>
```

Please use `text-decoration-none` for anchor class. That will solve your issue.